# TypeError: _this2.props.deleteTask is not a function

Tags: react-redux

**actions/index.js:**

```
export const addTask = (task)=> {

    return {
        type: "ADD_TASK",
        payload: task
    }
};


export const deleteTask = (task) =>{

    return {
        type:'DELETE_TASK',
        payload: task
    }
}; 

export default {addTask,deleteTask};
```

**Delete Button click function:**

```
<button onClick = {() => this.props.deleteTask(this.props.task)}>Delete</button>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: did you import it ?

Comment: You cannot export two components as default,export default {addTask,deleteTask}; Remove this and please show us how are you connecting to deleteTask action

Comment: function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({deleteTask},dispatch)
}


export default connect(()=>{return {};},mapDispatchToProps)(Task);

Comment: I imported as below

Comment: import deleteTask from '../../actions/index';

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the parent component of `<button />`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is obvious,

1. You cannot export multiple components by default. So there is no need of 
   `export default {addTask,deleteTask}`
2. And then you need to have a named import as `import {deleteTask} from '../../actions/index'`

After that it should work fine

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        deleteTask
    }, dispatch)
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Task);
```

Comment: export const addTask = (task)=> {
    return {
        type: "ADD_TASK",
        payload: task
    }
};
 
  const deleteTask = (taskId) =>{
    return {
        type:'DELETE_TASK',
        payload: taskId
    }
}; 

export default {deleteTask};

Comment: Can you try as I mentioned in my answer or `export default deleteTask`

Comment: Hi i am able to delete now,But always first item is deleting.

Comment: case 'DELETE_TASK':
            state = state.slice();
            state.splice(action.payload,1);
            break;

Comment: Please help me to resove this

Comment: First payload is task and not index of task, also can you ask a new question with the reducer code